# Balloon information on google maps in android

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm trying to apply the tutorial: http://deckjockey.blogspot.com/2010/01/android-baloon-display-on-map.html?showComment=1322215574598#c3178096297154271518 on my code, and I'm facing a small difficulty - it doesn' work,

here is my code:

```
    public void HuntCl(View v) throws UnknownHostException, IOException{
                     String sentenceX, sentenceY = null;           

   try {

    clientSocket = new Socket("10.0.2.2", 1234);
    Log.d("LatitudeE6", ""+point.getLatitudeE6());
    Log.d("LongitudeE6", ""+point.getLongitudeE6());
    DataOutputStream outToServer = new DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());        
    BufferedReader inFromServer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
    sentenceX = ""+point.getLatitudeE6();
    sentenceY = ""+point.getLongitudeE6();
    outToServer.writeBytes(sentenceX + " "+ sentenceY+'\n');

    String ciekawostka = inFromServer.readLine();
    String [] holder = ciekawostka.split("\\s+");

    for(int i =0; i<holder.length; i++){

    x = Integer.valueOf(holder[i]);
    y= Integer.valueOf(holder[i+1]);
    marker=getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.pin);
    marker.setBounds(0, 0, marker.getIntrinsicWidth(),
    marker.getIntrinsicHeight());
    POI funPlaces = new POI(marker,x,y);
    mapView.getOverlays().add(funPlaces);
    GeoPoint pt = funPlaces.getCenter(); 
    mapView.getController().setCenter(pt);
    }


   } catch (Exception e) {
       Log.d("error","TCP Error: " + e.toString());
   }

           }


class POI extends ItemizedOverlay {
        private List<OverlayItem> locations = new ArrayList<OverlayItem>();

        private Drawable marker;
    public POI(Drawable marker, int tX, int tY)
    {
    super(marker);
    this.marker=marker;

    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    BaloonLayout noteBaloon = (BaloonLayout) layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.ballon, null);


    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(200,100);
    layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_VERTICAL);
    layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
    noteBaloon.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

    mapView.removeView(noteBaloon);
    noteBaloon.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    // TextView textmsg = (TextView) noteBaloon.findViewById(R.id.note_text);
    TextView textmsg = (TextView) noteBaloon.findViewById(R.id.text);
    textmsg.setText("I am a Popup Balloon!!!");

    mapView.addView(noteBaloon, new MapView.LayoutParams(200,200,  new OverlayItem(new GeoPoint((int)(tX),(int)(tY)), "Seven Lagoon", "Seven Lagoon").getPoint(),MapView.LayoutParams.BOTTOM_CENTER));
    mapView.setEnabled(false); 


    locations.add(new OverlayItem(new GeoPoint((int)(tX),(int)(tY)), "Seven Lagoon", "Seven Lagoon"));

    populate();
    }
    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapView, boolean shadow) {

    super.draw(canvas, mapView, shadow);

    boundCenterBottom(marker);
    }
        @Override
        protected OverlayItem createItem(int i) {
        return locations.get(i);
        }
            @Override
            public int size() {
            return locations.size();
            }

            }

}
```

Comment: It doesn't work means? you got any error or nothing display?

Comment: damn, sorry :). Well it doesn't put the marker, and there is no balloon, but the map is working properly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[android-mapviewballoons](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-mapviewballoons) library provides an easy way to annotate map overlay items with a simple information balloon when using *Google Maps*. Create a subclass of

> BalloonItemizedOverlay

in the same way you would do for the base

> ItemizedOverlay

class.

Here is a sample output

[image]